# Filter and calculate % of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to calculate the % of men and women in a dataframe column named "gender".

"gender" is defined as an object taking 3 values : "Man" "Woman" "nan" (NA).

I did this :

```
total = len(df['gender'])
men = len(df[df['gender']=="Man"])
women = len(df[df['gender']=="Woman"])

pct_men = round(men/total*100,1)
pct_women = round(women/total*100,1)

print(f'{pct_men}%')
print(f'{pct_women}%')
```

But it returns 0.0% for both.

When i check 'total' value it returns : 10123033 but zero for both 'men' and 'women'
Thanks.

Comment: what is `pct_yes` and `pct_no`? Did you mean `pct_men` and `pct_women`

Comment: I think you mean `print(f'{pct_men}%')` and `print(f'{pct_women}%')`

Comment: Thanks ! Fixed it but this wasn't the problem. I don't know why my code worked days ago but not now

Comment: Are you sure you are using a Python 3.x version and not 2.x?

Comment: @MichaelButscher i am using a  3.7.3 version

Comment: can you try `((df['gender'].value_counts()/df['gender'].count())*100).apply(lambda x: round(x, 1))`? After that `print` the output here;

Comment: It seems that the real values in `gender` column are not exactly the three possible options (or all are "nan"). Try to print a sample of the column to check.

Comment: @Epsi95 Your code is working , thank you  !

Comment: @MichaelButscher You might be right but i did df.gender.unique()  and it gave me back these 3 possible values

Comment: There may be spaces or other invisible characters in the values. Retrieve one seemingly "Man" or "Woman" value and print its `repr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pay attention maybe in your dataframe "man" or "men" or "Men" exist instead of "Man" and for woman ...

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': {0: 'Man', 1:'Woman', 2:'Man'}})

total = len(df['gender'])
men = len(df[df['gender']=="Man"])
women = len(df[df['gender']=="Woman"])


pct_men = round(men/total*100,1)
pct_women = round(women/total*100,1)

print(f'{pct_men}%')
print(f'{pct_women}%')
```

output:

```
66.7%
33.3%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': {0: 'Man', 1:'Woman', 2:'Man', 3:None}})

df['gender'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

Out:

```
Man      66.666667
Woman    33.333333
Name: gender, dtype: float64
```

or if you'd like to include null:

```
df['gender'].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)*100
```

Out:

```
Man      50.0
NaN      25.0
Woman    25.0
Name: gender, dtype: float64
```